# Retrieving sub collection from firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to retrieve a sub collection from firestore database using Angular.
I have collection 'Company' containing fields 'Name' and 'Id' and subcollection 'CustomerList' containg fields 'Name' and 'Id'

To retreive Company collection I have code:

```
private companyCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Company>;
```

```
getCompany() {
  return this.company= 
    this.companyCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Company;
          return data;     
        });
```

My question is how to retreive 'CustomerList' sub collection and add it to 'Company' object.

Comment: Have you tried using the subscribe method to fetch the subcollection?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 things:

#### 1 If your collection is object like:

Before you check you need to define relations between your customers and companies.

```
interface customer {
 id: any;
 name: string;
}
interface Company { 
  id: any;
  name: string;
  customerList: customer[];
}
```

Here is very simple example:

```
const customers = [
 {
   id: 0,
   name: 'lilu',
 },
 {
   id: 1,
   name: 'lilu1',
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: 'lilu2',
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   name: 'lilu3',
 }
 ];

 const companies = [
 {
   id: 0,
   name: 'lilu Company',
 },
 {
    id: 1,
    name: 'lilu1 Company',
   },
 {
   id: 2,
   name: 'lilu2 Company',
 },
 {
id: 3,
name: 'lilu3 Company',
  },
  ];

  let customersWithCompanies = [];

  for (let item of companies) {
       let obj = {
         id: item.id,
          name: item.name,
           customerList: customers
          };
         customersWithCompanies.push(obj);
   }
    console.log(customersWithCompanies);
```

If this is collection prototype you need js/ts functions to get, set specific data and then push to firebase;

#### 2 You have to different collections in firebase and they are connected to each other (Mayby on Idea level)

In this case you need to fetch data from different collections here is part of code from documentation.

From firebase documentation you need to define it like this:

```
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const alovelaceDocumentRef = doc(db, 'users/alovelace');
```

Please view followin url: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#web-version-9_2

If I didn't catch subject well please wite a comend and I'll make answer more clear with examples.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but its not what im looking for. By default query in firestore doesnt return subcollections. my question is it possible to modify my method so it returns Observable containing sub collection as well. Firebase documentation doesnt have samples for Angular (not JS).